# How to delete child entity after parent entity deleted in Room database?

Tags: android, android-room

I have two class

```kotlin
@Entity
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var uid: Int = 0,
    var name: String?
)

@Entity
data class Note(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var nid: Int = 0,
    var title: String,
    var description: String?,
    var authorId: Int
)
```

There was one to many relationship between `User` and `Note`:

```kotlin
data class UserWithNotes(
    @Embedded val user: User,
    @Relation(parentColumn = "uid", entityColumn = "authorId")
    var notes: List<Note>
)
```

By default, if I delete the `User`, the `authorId` field in `Note` will be set to null. How can I delete all `Note` after `User` deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Make `authorId` variable in `Note` as `ForeignKey` either by annotating variable with `ForeignKey` annotation or by setting foreignKey variable in `Entity` annotation.

```
@Entity(
   foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = User::class,
            parentColumns = ["uid"],
            childColumns = ["authorId"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class Note(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var nid: Int = 0,
    var title: String,
    var description: String?,
    var authorId: Int
)
```

refer this link for better understanding: [Room-ForeignKey](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/ForeignKey)

Comment: So, if I want to delete all `Note` after `User` deleted, I have to use `foreighKeys`, and the `@Relation` can't do that?

Comment: `@Relation` annotation is used to fetch data child table based on data from parent table. But with `@ForeignKey` annotation by deleting a record in parent table will delete the associated rows in child table.